# how can I make my .bat file continue after an error

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a .bat file in windows that does three things

```
cmd1 arg1 arg2
cmd2 arg3 
cmd3 arg4 arg5 arg6
```

Sometimes cmd1 can fail and that's fine, I would like to carry on and execute cmd2 and cmd3. But my bat stops at cmd1. How can I avoid this?

**Update** for clarity - these are not other .bat files, they are exe commands. Hopefully I don't have to build a tree of .bat files just to achieve this.

Comment: You should be able to start the command using [`cmd /C`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/74321/259953).

Comment: You need to show a specific code example of what is not working. Batch files normally do not terminate automatically if a command fails with an error. Batch files do terminate if there is a syntax error. If your code is exiting upon an exe error, then there must be logic in your code that is causing that behavior.

Answer (score 36):

Another option is to use the amperstand (`&`)

`cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3`

If you use a double, it only carries on if the previous command completes successfully (`%ERRORLEVEL%==0`)

`cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`

If you use a double pipe (`||`), it only runs the next command if the previous completes with an error code (`%ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0`)

`cmd1 || cmd2 || cmd3`

Comment: Can I do this when passing args also? I just tried and it didn't see to work.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob I do all the time... I have a `CHKDSK` command, with arguments, that works. I type `check D: & check E: & check F:`, and it works. The arguments the BAT file has include the `/perf /f /r /b /scan` switches

Comment: good one! brought me an idea how to implement several retries: cmd || cmd || ... will execute next cmd until succeeds

Comment: This makes long scripts unreadable, is there no other way?

Comment: @Jan how does it make long scripts unreadable?

Comment: @CanadianLuke because 100 commands in 100 lines need to be concatenated to one big line. No empty lines for separation of blocks of code can be used.

Comment: If you're running a hundred programs from one batch file, I'd question the reason, @Jan. There are other ways of doing it, but for only a few commands, this is my preferred way.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Well batch is the windows batch framework. How do you run hundreds of commands non interactively? Is there a better approach in the power shell? Is that worse to move there?

Comment: There are many other ways, but you'd be splitting up the sets of commands into different scripts. Write scripts that do a few commands amazingly, then call them from other scripts. When I image systems, I run a batch file that installs extra programs, runs vbs scripts, runs other batch files, runs PowerShell scripts, and they all do their specific jobs perfectly

Comment: that helps my node start command in package.json thanks

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
cmd.exe /c cmd1 arg1
cmd2
...
```

This uses `cmd.exe` to execute the command in a new instance of the Windows command interpreter, so a failed command doesn't interrupt the batch script. The `/c` flag tells the interpreter to terminate as soon as the command finishes executing.

`cmd2` executes even if the first command fails. See `cmd /?` from Windows Command Prompt for more information.

Answer (score 19):

Presumming the cmds are other .bat files stack the commands like this:

```
 call cmd1
 call cmd2
 call cmd3
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Canadian Luke's answer](https://superuser.com/a/527827/43051), if you want to keep your script a little more organized you can use `^` to continue the command chain in a new line in your script, like this:

```
scoop install windows-terminal & ^
scoop install joplin & ^
scoop install neovim & ^
scoop install autohotkey & ^
... & ^
scoop update -a
```

Instead of the ugly

```
scoop install windows-terminal & scoop install joplin & scoop install neovim & ...
```